Why aren’t all of the Alien movies available as true 4K transfers?
The first 4 movies in the Alien franchise were shot on film, and have since been released to home media in 4K versions.
It is puzzling to me that out of these, only Alien has had a 4K scan made from the original film. The others have all had 4K upscales, which are not the same thing.
Is there a technical issue or a commercial? Copyrights?

@blobbymcblobby it seems that while the movies have been released as 4k ultra, only the original Alien has actually been mastered from a 4k print, and the rest have been upscaled from 2k masters. At least, as far as various internet discussions I've found seem to indicate

ugh, i had a quick delve into it, not a fan of what JC is doing to his movies. I don't mind me some grain, but I hate what the AI is doing (and i occasionally have to work with AI tools) yikes. Elsewhere it seems to read that aside from Alien, others were scanned and mastered at 2K, then upscaled to 4K - reason? budget... its cheaper and the great unwashed plebs neither care nor notice...

@HorusKol I’m curious, what do you mean by a “4K print”? To me the word “print” means “analog film copy of the analog master”. I guess same question for the asker.

@ToddWilcox I mean that they went back to the original film and scanned it to produce the 4k video, instead of upscaling a 2k version made for an earlier release.

I’ve edited the question in view of HorusKol’s clarification
